# jQuery UI drop event of droppable fires on sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of elements that can be dropped into a list of (existing) sortables.
When a droppable element is dropped into the sortables, I want to modify the element. I do this by calling the drop event of droppable.

But it seems this drop event is also fired when the sortable elements are sorted inside sortable. And I only want to modify the dropped element when dropped-in from the outside.

```
$('#sortable').sortable().droppable({
// Drop should only fire when a draggable element is dropped into the sortables,
// and NOT when the sortables themselves are sorted (without something being dragged into).
drop: function(ev, ui){
    $(ui.draggable).html('<div>TEMPLATE</div>');
}
});
$('#draggables li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#sortable',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move'
});​
```

[Complete example on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxpMn/1/).

How can I modify a dropped-in element without modifying them when sorted inside of sortable?

Comment: The reason this is happening appears to be that sortable items have the properties of draggable items by default - at least according to the documentation. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue from a different angle. My `sortable/droppable` was firing off an `over` event and a `drop` event when all I wanted was the `drop` event. Using your code, here's how I fixed it:

```
    $('#sortable').sortable()
    $('#draggables li').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#sortable',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid',
        cursor: 'move'
    });
    ​$('#sortable').sortable('disable'); 
    // disable the *sortable* functionality while retaining the *droppable*
    $('#sortable').droppable({
    // Drop should only fire when a draggable element is dropped into the sortables,
    // and NOT when the sortables themselves are sorted (without something being dragged into).
    drop: function(ev, ui){
        $(ui.draggable).html('<div>TEMPLATE</div>');
    }
    });
```

The only disadvantage is that all functionality within the `sortable.update` event must now be placed in the `droppable.drop` event.

Comment: By the looks of your code, and after attempting it, all that `$("#sortable").sortable('disable');` does is disable all of the sortable functionality entirely, making the list unsortable 100% of the time. I am only not downvoting because, I might be in error?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `sortreceive` event of the sortable. This event is fired when a new element is inserted into the sortable.

Via `ui.helper` you can access your newly inserted element.

```
  $('#sortable').sortable().droppable().on('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {
    var inserted_element = $(ui.helper);
    // modify your element
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this can help :

> See this fiddle for code, I change it:

http://jsfiddle.net/penjepitkertasku/CxpMn/34/

```
$('#sortable').sortable();
$('#sortable').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui){
        $(ui.draggable).html('<div>' + ui.draggable.text() + '</div>');
    }
});
$('#draggables li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#sortable',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move'
});
```