# jQuery UI drop event of droppable firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

**Html**

```
<div id="dropableArea">Drop area</div>
<ul>
    <li class="dragModule">Item 1</li>
    <li class="dragModule">Item 2</li>
    <li class="dragModule">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.dragModule').draggable({connectToSortable:'#dropableArea',helper: 'clone'});

    $('#dropableArea').droppable({
        accept: '.dragModule',
        activeClass:'active-droppable',
        drop:function(){
            console.log('drop');
        }
    });

    $('#dropableArea').sortable({accept: '.dragModule',connectWith: '#dropableArea',revert: true,});
    $("#dropableArea").disableSelection();
});
```

My issue is that I console console.log('drop'); this is a droppable callback drop function and it's called twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI drop event of droppable widget firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664641/jquery-ui-drop-event-of-droppable-widget-firing-twice)

Comment: have you found answer ? if not please message me

Comment: @melvin I didn't find my answer. can you help me?

Comment: @Bhautik Sure. I will update you after my office hours

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with jQuery UI. The issue occurs when you use droppable and sortable on same element. Here you are using droppable and sortable on same element `droppableArea`
Inorder to solve this, instead of `drop` method of `droppable` use `recieve` method of `sortable`. Both does the same thing in your case.

Check the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/bf6v5nm1/7/)

```
$(function() {
  $('.dragModule').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#dropableArea',
    helper: 'clone'
  });

  $('#dropableArea').droppable({
    accept: '.dragModule',
    activeClass: 'active-droppable'
  });

  $('#dropableArea').sortable({
    accept: '.dragModule',
    connectWith: '#dropableArea',
    revert: true,
    receive: function (event, ui) {      
       console.log("drop");
    }
  });
  $("#dropableArea").disableSelection();
});
```

Change the code as above and it will solve the issues. Please let me know if the issue is resolved

**#UPDATE**

You can add the following code in sortable function

```
 beforeStop : function (event, ui) {      
   ui.helper.html('hello');
 }
```

Comment: i updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fbov9qgw/ Why droppable area remove my elment id?

Comment: @Bhautik because you are cloning the element. You are using `helper:clone` in draggable. Also no elements can have same `id` in the same page

Comment: What if i have to change html of draged element after dropped on droppable area.

Comment: you need to add `beforeStop` method in sortable and update `ui.helper` to change html. See the update section in my answer. Please mark this as answer since it has solved your question

Comment: Yes it's help me but it's call every time i sort the element. once element dropped and change html after i only do rearrange the order of element,

Comment: @Bhautik First of all can you explain your requirement ? Once you explain i can help you in the right way. Also please mark this as answer for the efforts i made

Comment: thanks for replying. Actually i am developing a plugin that have drag and drop functionality like mailchimp i have to do similar like mailchimp like drag module from one side area and dropped to other are while dropped dragged element change to custom element and that module have settings that change style of that module and also sort the module and so any things. And please do upvote my question also so people can see.

Comment: @Bhautik I have upvoted your question. Would you mind accepting the answer ? I will update a fiddle where you can see what you need

Comment: @Bhautik What you asked for was droppable firing twice. I have answered for that. You are asking for additional help

Comment: sorry but i need drop callback event and i also need use droppable area for other features. I know that sortable received callback solved my current problem but it not give me what i received in droppable area.

Comment: @Bhautik You should change your logic. Sortable receive solved your current issue. Instead of using droppable, call another sortable for the content in droppable area

Comment: can we chat in chat room

Comment: sure. now i am busy with work. Will notify you (probably after 9 hours)

Comment: @Bhautik Tell me.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191773/jquery-ui-drag-and-drop please join in this discussion.