# How to add class to the cloned div when it is dropped to the sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to add some class to each clone of 'mydraggable' when it is dropped inside the sortable. But I am not sure of how to acheive this. I also wants to make the dropped clone of mydraggable as sortable so that if I drop something inside of the newly cloned inside droppable It should function same as parent sortable.

Following is my HTML

```
<div id="mydraggable"  >I am First<span class="myhandler">DRAG<span></div>
<div id ="sortable" class="mysortable" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Following is my JS

```
  <script>


   $('#mydraggable').draggable({
   connectToSortable: ".mysortable",
  helper: "clone",
  revert:"invalid",
   });

 $( ".mysortable" ).sortable({ 
    placeholder: "highlight_me",
    cursor: "move",
    handle: ".myhandler",
    revert: true,
    receive:function(event , ui){
        alert($(this).html());
        //$(this).addClass('ui-sortable');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$(ui.item).addClass("ui-sortable");
```

**Complete Code:**

```
$( ".mysortable" ).sortable({ 
 placeholder: "highlight_me",
 cursor: "move",
 handle: ".myhandler",
 revert: true,
 receive:function(event , ui){
    $(ui.item).addClass("ui-sortable");
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but the newly made div in sortable is not functioning like original.. I want that even the newly made div in sortable should act same as that of parent.

Comment: @ShivekParmar: what do you mean should act same. If its about same events of that of parents then you need to bind the events after receive.

Comment: i want the dropped element to be able to accept clones that are dropped in it.. If you can demo fiddle option then it would be great.

Comment: Here is my fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shivek/gbkwzhxa/). I want it in such a way that when it is dropped then it should also be able to accept like its parent.

Comment: The class is added to the original draggable but I want the class to be added to the draggable ONLY WHEN it is DROPPED inside the sortable. Please help me. I am stuck with this for 2 days.

Comment: @ShivekParmar: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13456222/1719752 to only make it work on drop.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the item being dropped using `ui.item` and add the class like

```
$(ui.item).addClass('ui-sortable');
```

If i understood correctly, You need to use the [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) method so that the newly added items in sortable are recognized.

Something like

```
$( ".mysortable" ).sortable({ 
  placeholder: "highlight_me",
  cursor: "move",
  handle: ".myhandler",
  revert: true,
  receive:function(event , ui){
    alert($(this).html());
    $(ui.item).addClass('ui-sortable');
    $(this).sortable("refresh");
 }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/ng1rzj7x/)

Comment: I have checked the element with inspect element of browser but the class is not added.Please provide demo on fiddle.

Comment: @ShivekParmar looks like it isn't working for the first time if you're listening to receive. You can use `update` instead like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/ng1rzj7x/) (*receive is called before update, ui might not have finished something, still not sure why it doesn't work for the first time alone...*)

Comment: thanks for reply and fiddle but can we do that after dropping new element, the new element is able to accept other elements.

Comment: @ShivekParmar the draggable in your question only contains some text. How do you drag something in-between text..? Please update the question properly...

Comment: Here is the website for live example what I want. But I don't know how to achieve it.. [Layoutit](http://www.layoutit.com/build?r=77343403). See when we are Dropping any new column elements then they are capable of accepting new elements like its parent.